# Possible to create 'Custom Reports' based on Variable Data in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, webdriver, jenkins-plugins

Possible to create 'Custom Reports' based on Variable Data in Jenkins?

```
 1. Lets say I check the response time of webdriver retrieving a URL: www.example.com 
 2. Based on the following forumla: 
StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
pageLoad.start();
        pageLoad.stop();
        long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
        long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
        long pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder = (pageLoadTime_ms % 1000);
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + "Seconds:" + pageLoadTime_Seconds + ", Remainder:" + pageLoadTime_SecondsRemainder);
```

3. Is there a report in jenkins which will generate figure based on a Java variable such as the following: pageLoadTime_Seconds?

Comment: "Custom reports" alone doesn't mean anything. Though you could write this to a CSV file and use the [Plot Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plot) to graph the data.

Comment: @Christopher Orr is there a report inside jenkins which in turn could plot data based on java variables

Comment: Like I was saying in my first comment, you could run your Java, have it output its data to a CSV file, which the Plot Plugin can use.

Comment: @Christopher Orr  excellent excellent  excellent